# For Loop / Switch Optimisation

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, switch-statement

I have a `for loop` to cycle through and array and a `switch` statement to match values. When there is a match, I append a `<div>` to the body. Now, I am using the index of the current loop in the append and was wondering if there is a simpler way (though this is not crazy as is).

My main interest is to see if there is a way to avoid rewriting this line...

```
$("#cssLiveConsole").append("<div id='cssLive" + styles[s] + "' class='option-wrap'>" + styles[s] + "</div>");
```

Here is the `loop` and `switch`

```
        var s;
        for (s = 0; s < styles.length; s += 1) {
            switch (styles[s]) {
            case "font-family":
                console.log(styles[s]); // **For Testing - Removable**
                $("#cssLiveConsole").append("<div id='cssLive" + styles[s] + "' class='option-wrap'>" + styles[s] + "</div>");
                break;
            case "font-size":
                console.log(styles[s]); // **For Testing - Removable**
                $("#cssLiveConsole").append("<div id='cssLive" + styles[s] + "' class='option-wrap'>" + styles[s] + "</div>");
                break;
            case "font-color":
                console.log(styles[s]); // **For Testing - Removable**
                $("#cssLiveConsole").append("<div id='cssLive" + styles[s] + "' class='option-wrap'>" + styles[s] + "</div>");
                break;
            case "font-hover":
                console.log(styles[s]); // **For Testing - Removable**
                $("#cssLiveConsole").append("<div id='cssLive" + styles[s] + "' class='option-wrap'>" + styles[s] + "</div>");
                break;
            case "background-color":
                console.log(styles[s]); // **For Testing - Removable**
                $("#cssLiveConsole").append("<div id='cssLive" + styles[s] + "' class='option-wrap'>" + styles[s] + "</div>");
                break;
            case "background-hover":
                console.log(styles[s]); // **For Testing - Removable**
                $("#cssLiveConsole").append("<div id='cssLive" + styles[s] + "' class='option-wrap'>" + styles[s] + "</div>");
                break;
            }
        }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This would be better suited to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: The code in every case is exactly the same ...

Comment: @null Looks like most of the questions on there are of the same matter as here...

Comment: Whats your point @Pointy?

Comment: @VIDesignz Code Review is for working solutions which need optimising, SO is for code with actual errors/problems

Comment: @VIDesignz Why do you need all those switches *at all* if you're going to do *exactly the same thing* for each value? See the answer from MTO below.

Comment: @Pointy This is why I posted the question...the line of code is the same yes, yet the actual output of each would be different and should only be triggered if a value from the `style` array is matched. I have looked at @MTO 's answer and it is exactly what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var acceptable = ['font-family', 'font-size', 'font-color', 'font-hover', 'background-color', 'background-hover'];

$.each(styles, function(i, style){
    if($.inArray(style, acceptable)){
        $("#cssLiveConsole").append("<div id='cssLive" + styles[i] + "' class='option-wrap'>" + styles[i] + "</div>");
    }
});
```

Comment: I have never seen `$.inArray`...looks promising though. Do you know if it would be looping through both arrays? Such as `style * array`...or create and Index array and match against that...just curious

Comment: @VIDesignz `$.each(styles` is going to iterate all of the styles. Later on down the line, it's going to match the key that `style` is, against the keys in `acceptable`. so it will be looping through `acceptable` for the key of `style`

Comment: I see..so it would be equivalent in performance as @MTO 's answer I would say.

Comment: @VIDesignz In the case of my answer, it will actually be a bit faster. [Here's a jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/in-array-vs-for-test)

Comment: Can you help me understand one thing though...how are these arguments being set here? `$.each(styles, function(i, style){});`

Comment: Actually, I see that it passes the index/value when iterating over an array. Awesome stuff! Thanks again man!

Answer (score 3):

```
    var tests = {
        'font-family': true,
        'font-size': true,
        'font-color': true,
        'font-hover': true,
        'background-color': true,
        'background-hover': true
    };
    for (var s = 0; s < styles.length; ++s ) {
        if ( tests[styles[s]] )
        {
            console.log(styles[s]); // **For Testing - Removable**
            $("#cssLiveConsole").append("<div id='cssLive" + styles[s] + "' class='option-wrap'>" + styles[s] + "</div>");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I like this approach, seems like it would be good on performance as well.